# Why can any quantum channel be represented as a matrix?

Tags: quantum-operation, kraus-representation

In [this](https://www-m5.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M5/Allgemeines/MichaelWolf/QChannelLecture.pdf) PDF (page 43), it is argued that, given an arbitrary quantum channel with Kraus decomposition:

$$ E(\rho) = \sum_{j} K_j \rho K_j^{\dagger} $$

Such map can be represented with a matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{d²}$:

$$ \hat E = \sum_j K_j \otimes \bar{K_j} $$

I can't figure out a proof, do you have any ideas?

Comment: $\rho$ is an element of a vector space with $n^2$ elements. If you stack the columns of $\rho$ on top of one another you'll get a vector in the standard column vector form. Then the linear transformation $E(\rho)$ should be representable by a matrix. You can try to show that the matrix that represents its action is $\hat{E}$. Hint: try to prove $\mathrm{vec}(AXB) = A\otimes B^T \mathrm{vec}(X)$ where $\mathrm{vec}$ is the column stacking map.

Comment: this is also often referred to as the *natural representation* of the channel. See eg https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/

Comment: Every linear function between finite-dimensional vector spaces can be represented as a matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mind that $E\left( \cdot \right) $ is a linear map, and [can be written](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785040/can-any-linear-transformation-be-represented-by-a-matrix) as matrix act on a vector. If we write matrix in vector form as follows:
$$\operatorname{vec}_c(\rho)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\rho_{00} \\
\rho_{10} \\
\vdots \\
\rho_{n n}
\end{array}\right)$$
With this form, you can check one fact:$K_j\rho $ has vector form $K_j\otimes I\mathrm{vec}\left( \rho \right) $  and ${\rho K_j}$ has vector form $I\otimes {K_j}^T\mathrm{vec}\left( \rho \right) $, combine them together we have $K_j\rho K_{j}^{\dagger}$ has vector form $K_j\otimes \bar{K}_j\mathrm{vec}\left( \rho \right) $.
**Edit** Okay, I made a mistake. In your pdf link, the author state he do the vectorization in style $|k\rangle\langle l|\leftrightarrow| k, l\rangle$, this is actually stack rows of matrix, i.e. $$\text{vec}_r\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta\\
\gamma & \delta
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\gamma\\
\delta
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
With vec$_c$, we should have [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)):$${\displaystyle \operatorname {vec}_c (ABC)=(C^{\mathrm {T} }\otimes A)\operatorname {vec} (B)}$$
Hence we have$$
\mathrm{vec}_{\mathrm{r}}\left( E_j\rho E_{j}^{\dagger} \right) =\mathrm{vec}_c\left( \bar{E}_j\rho ^TE_{j}^{T} \right) =E_j\otimes \bar{E}_j\mathrm{vec}_c\left( \rho ^T \right) =E_j\otimes \bar{E}_j\mathrm{vec}_r\left( \rho \right) 
$$